# Reversing each scalar of an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

How do you reverse each string in an array of say three strings without reversing the order of the strings within the array?

Here is my program and the last command is where I try to take each element of the array and reverse it. For example: if I put it `Andy Sam` as input I want to get back `ydnA maS`, not `maS ydnA`. What am I doing wrong?

I thought that if I put the input into array @ref and took each element of that array via a `foreach` loop and reversed each element that it should turn out right.

```
print "Please enter your name: \n";

$userinput = <STDIN>;
chomp ($userinput);

@ref = $userinput;
print "Hello, $userinput.\n";

@get_characters = split(/ /, $userinput);
$strin = join ("" , @get_characters);
$m = length $strin;
print "Your name has ", "$m" , " characters in it.\n";

foreach $e(@ref)
{
    $e = reverse $e;
    print $e;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that the array that you're iterating on has only one element.  You need to split the name to get individual words:

```
my @ref = $userinput; # <-- contains a single string.
my @words = split ' ', $userinput;
```

Then juse use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).  The only trick is that you have to force a [`scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) context.

```
my @words = qw(Andy Sam);
@words = map {scalar reverse} @words;
print "@words";
```

Outputs:

```
ydnA maS
```

Could also use a for loop to edit the same array:

```
$_ = reverse for @words;
```